# PHP codeigniter login error using flex auth

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter 3, and I am struggling to make a simple login using flex auth, but it is not working at all.. The code used is similar to the one below:

```
function login_via_ajax()
{
    if ($this->input->is_ajax_request())
    {
        $this->load->model('pat_auth_model');
        $this->pat_auth_model->login_via_ajax();

        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->flexi_auth->get_messages());
        if ($this->flexi_auth->is_logged_in()) {
            $this->errorData['success'] = true;
        } else {
            $this->errorData['success'] = false;
        }
        $this->errorData['message'] = (! isset($this->errorData['message'])) ? $this->session->flashdata('message') : $this->errorData['message'];  
        die(json_encode($this->errorData));
    }
    else
    {
        /* Load Template */
        $this->template->auth_render('auth/login', $this->data);
    }
}
```

As supposed, if the username and password are correct, the jQuery script below should have toked me to the desired page:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('form').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var submit_url = $(this).attr('action');

            var $form_inputs = $(this).find(':input');
            var form_data = {};
            $form_inputs.each(function() {
                form_data[this.name] = $(this).val();
            });

            $.ajax({
                url: submit_url,
                type: 'POST',
                data: form_data,
                dataType: 'json',
                success:function(data) {
                    if (data['success'] == true) {
                        window.location.href = "<?= base_url();?>admin/dashboard"      
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#ajxError').html('<button class="close" data-close="alert"></button>'+data['message']);
                        $('#ajxError').show();
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I tried even to get the session variables like this:

```
die(print_r($this->session->userdata()));  //print all session data
```

It seems that the app is granting permissions to the user and then deletes all session variables and then gets me back to the login page..

Does anyone know how to deal with that?

Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at your browser's developer tools network tab, see what session cookie is coming back via Ajax and see what session cookie comes back on the next response.

Comment: Are you sure that flexi auth is compatible with codeigniter 3?